# From Bessel's inequality to say

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Bessel's inequality is

Let $\{ e_1,e_2, \ldots \}$ be an orthonormal sequence in an inner-product space $\mathcal{X}$. For any $x \in \mathcal{X}, \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i\rangle^2 \leq \Vert x\Vert^2$ and therefore $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$ converges in $\mathcal{X}$.

Question: In Bessel's inequality, it is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i\rangle^2 \leq \Vert x\Vert^2$. Why we can say $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$ converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in a Hilbert space, we can use the fact that $\{e_k\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal sequence. $$\left\|\sum_{k=M}^{N} \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k\right\|^2 = \sum_{k=M}^N |\langle x, e_k\rangle|^2 \to 0,$$ as $N,M \to \infty$, since $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is Bessel.

Comment: How to get the first equality?

Comment: @Jonathen: $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is orthonormal sequence.

Comment: I am still confused.

Comment: @Jonathen: If $x \perp y$, then $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$. What can we then say about $\|x + y\|^2$?

Comment: @Jonathen Note that we can change square of norm to inner product (in any inner product space in which Hilbert spaces are part of). i.e. $||x||^2=\langle x, x \rangle$. This is almost always a useful trick to keep in mind when dealing with such space

Comment: @Jin Then I can find $||x+y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2$

Comment: I see. The key point here is $\langle x, e_i \rangle e_i \perp \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j$